# android - best way to maintain camera preview after stopPreview and orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera

Ive built plenty of camera related apps before but they always were built in an activity where I had locked the view to landscape or portrait after the user took the picture. However this new apps requirements call for allowing the image caught onscreen to be allowed to rotate after I call camera.stopPreview(). Ive thought about doing it like this.....

1.)store the byte from my picture call back and put it in a bundle

2.)in my onResume check if the bundle != null and if not grab the byte array

3.)since I put my surfaceView inside a frameLayout I could replace the surfaceView temporarily 
with an imageView and use bitmapfactory.decodebytearray() to create the bitmap image for the imageview.

now I know I can get that all to work just fine but is there a way to just pass the camera preview or something so I dont have to go extra lengths to reach my requirement? Also the less bitmaps I have to create and store the better off Id be memory wise which is why I dont just go and do that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using this in my picture call back

```
if(getScreenOrientation()==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
         }else{
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
         }
```

then in one of my buttons I used

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

to turn it all back on so it would rotate again